# why iterator still exists in java

Tags: java, iterator

As per my knowledge the main difference between Iterator and ListIterator is

**Iterator :** Enables you to cycle through a collection in the forward direction only, for obtaining or removing elements

**ListIterator :** It extends Iterator, allow bidirectional traversal of list and the modification of elements

If ListIterator is more powerful than Iterator then sun java developer should have provide implementation for ListIterator only and deprecate iterator. Why Iterator is still exists in java? Is there any advantage of using Iterator than ListIterator?

Comment: Same argument for singly-linked list vs doubly-linked list.

Comment: Same answer for singly-linked list vs doubly-linked list. A doubly-linked list has a higher memory and computational overhead which is not appropriate in all situations.

Comment: Not quite the same answer.  Iterators could be used in your own custom classes, and it is the access contract that usually drives iterator design, not the overhead of the iterator itself - E.g. an iterator for a network stream would have to be forward-only.  With a single vs doubly-liked list, the choice is purely for overhead.

Comment: Deprecations and removals should never be made haphazardly.  Think of all the code that would break if every time something "more powerful" is added the "less powerful" thing is removed.  Never underestimate the value of preserving backwards compatibility.

Comment: @aroth: Well, considering `ListIterator` inherits from `Iterator`, I am not sure you really could deprecate it, even if you wanted to :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because not all collections support both forward and backward iteration. `ListIterators` are specifically for collections that have list semantics, i.e. they define an ordering over the elements. Some collection types (`Sets`, for example) do *not* define the ordering of their elements, so a `ListIterator` does not make sense for them.

There is also an extra overhead incurred when the iterator implementation needs to maintain enough state to support forward and backward iteration and in-place modification. By supporting both `Iterator` and `ListIterator` it is possible to have a light-weight implementation of `Iterator` when it is needed, and a heavier `ListIterator` for those cases where the extra functionality is required.

Comment: +1 and removing `Iterator` would create a lot of problems to legacy code, even if `Set` could be bidirectional

Comment: @Cameron, Its great response from you

Answer (score 6):

Just because something can do more, doesn't make it the right tool for the job.

In the case of `Iterator` vs. `ListIterator`, not every collection needs support for bidirectional iteration. Also, the amount of mutating power that the `ListIterator` has is not necessarily appropriate for general iteration. Lastly, `ListIterator` provides ways of accessing the index of an element, but many collections do not have a notion of an index. So you could say that the `ListIterator` is *too* powerful for most collections. In fact, some people may already consider `Iterator` to be "too powerful", as it provides a `remove` method, which is not always appropriate either.

The basic guiding factor here is the "List" part of `ListIterator`; while `Iterator` should be useful for all collections, `ListIterator` is specifically intended for collections which, like lists, have a well-defined linear ordering of their elements.

Some examples of where `ListIterator` would be useful:

- Singly & Doubly Linked Lists
- Array Lists
- Other collections with a well-defined linear ordering

Some examples of where `ListIterator` is *not* suited:

- Trees (many of them, anyways)
- Maps
- Sets
- Other collection which don't have a linear ordering

Answer (score 0):

The power of the ListIterator comes at a cost (implementation) which would be non-trivial for non-list-style collection types like hash maps, sets etc. That's why it is only required for index-accessible collections in the Java collection framework. Also, Iterator is the underlying device in Java's foreach kind of loop, and it makes sense to back such language features up with something simple, so that it can be adapted for a wider range of types more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Java is backwards-binary-compatible by design and intent, so nothing has ever been removed from it, apart from the AWT event migration of 1.0->1.1.